# Can there exist a statement whose truth value I cannot determine?

Tags: logic

Given a set of axioms can there exist a statement $P$ whose truth value can not be determined? $P$ is either true or false independently of the existence of a proof ( is it? ). So... that means that the given set of axioms does not adequalely characterize the undelying mathematical structure?

Or maybe it is the case that under the assumption that statements are either true or false there can not exist such a set of axioms?

Also I am unsure of what tags to use, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: See [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) and see [Undecidable mathematical statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem#Examples_of_undecidable_statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Take the empty set as your set of axioms. Given that, the truth of any statement that is neither true or false on purely logical grounds cannot be determined.

Of course, that is a silly example ... but the point still stands: yes, of course you can have axiom sets that are incomplete with regard to some domain.

What is a more inteesting question, is whether you can have an axiom system that *is* complete with regard to some domain. And, while for some 'simple' domains you can, for something like basic arithmetic (addition and multiplication on the natural numbers) it turns out that *any* (recursive and consistent) axiom set is incomplete. This is the famous Godel's Incompleteness Theorem.